# Need to append / delete id into hidden field on "change"

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden-field

I ve got numérous checkboxes in my page, each time I click a checkbox, I get the id im interested in and I fill a hidden form. My script is working but if I unclick the checkbox, it should delete the id from the hidden field (right now it appends again the id in the hidden field). How can I writte such a script ? Here's my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var string = "";


  $('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var subscription_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    if(string == "") {
      string = subscription_id;
    } else {
      string = string + ", " + subscription_id;
    }
    $('#select_players').val(string);
    $('#subscription_ids_export').val(string);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify this by retrieving only the `subscription_id` values from checkboxes which are checked instead of adding/removing values each time.

Try this:

```
$('.checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var subscriptionIds = $('.checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).parent().prop('id');
    }).get().join(',');
    $('#select_players').val(subscriptionIds);
    $('#subscription_ids_export').val(subscriptionIds);
})
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ymantcoj/)

Comment: very nice approach, I was thinking of checking is(:checked) but this is better

Comment: @DavidGeismar, why is it not working? Give more detail. Have you seen the fiddle?

Comment: I think it doesnt work because in my html `$('.checkbox:checked')` doesnt return anything as I never see a checked attribute in my html even when the checkboxes are checked

Comment: @DavidGeismar you shouldn't need to. The `:checked` selector works on the `checked` property which is set implicitly when the element is checked.